# Hardy inequality punctured space

Tags: lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

given the minimization problem:

$inf \ \frac{\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p  }{ \int_{\Omega} \frac{|u|^p}{|x|^p} } ,\ \ p>1$

infimum taken on all smooth functions with compact support in the punctured space: $R^n-{0}$

how can I show that it is enough to take the infimum just on all radially symmetric

functions in the punctured space?

note :we have the classical inequality :

$\int_{R^n}|\nabla u|^p>= \left (\frac{n-p}{p} \right )^p\int_{R^n} \frac{|u|^p}{|x|^p}$

for all smooth functions with compact support